# Data em orientação a objetos PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou começando aprender Orientação a Objetos, gostaria de saber como faço para usar data com `php`, porque no Java tem como importar o `java util`, mas no `php` não sei como faço, vou mostrar meu código:

```
<?php

abstract class DadosPessoais {
protected $nome, $funcao, $rg, $cpf, $data_adm, $login, $senha;


abstract function logar();  



function getNome() {
    return $this->nome;
}

function getFuncao() {
    return $this->funcao;
}

function getRg() {
    return $this->rg;
}

function getCpf() {
    return $this->cpf;
}

function getData_adm() {
    return $this->data_adm;
}

function getLogin() {
    return $this->login;
}

function getSenha() {
    return $this->senha;
}

function setNome($nome) {
    $this->nome = $nome;
}

function setFuncao($funcao) {
    $this->funcao = $funcao;
}

function setRg($rg) {
    $this->rg = $rg;
}

function setCpf($cpf) {
    $this->cpf = $cpf;
}

function setData_adm($data_adm) {
    $this->data_adm = new DateTime($data_adm);        
}

function setLogin($login) {
    $this->login = $login;
}

function setSenha($senha) {
    $this->senha = $senha;
}
}
```

Comment: Pode usar a classe DateTime

Comment: já tentei usar da seguinte forma: $funcionario ->$this->setData_adm(DateTime($data_adm));
Mas não dá certo, acho que estou errando na digitação de algo.

Comment: Só faltou o `new`. `$funcionario ->$this->setData_adm(new DateTime($data_adm));` ;)

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu coloco esta linha de código quando eu chamo um objeto que tem num construtor?

$funcionario = new Funcionario
               ("nome", "funcao", rg, cpf, AQUI É A DATA, "login", "senha");

Comment: Só colocar um `new DateTime($data_adm)`

Comment: Coloquei este código no metodo Setters, porém como faço para formatar essa data? com dia/mes/ano?

 function setData_adm($data_adm) {
        $this->data_adm = new DateTime($data_adm);        
    }

Pois ao colocar o código acima me retorna alinha abaixo:

[data_adm:protected] => 2002-04-04

Comment: `echo $objetoDate->format('d/m/Y');`

Comment: Não deu certo, na verdade deixa eu explicar melhor porque estou aprendendo agora, Eu tenho uma classe Funcionario, nesta classe há um construtor que ao ser instanciado preciso colocar as informações como: $nome, $funcao, $rg, $cpf, $data_adm, $login, $senha ...... então quando dou um print_r na tela a data não aparece formatada, acho que tenho que formatar dentro da classe Funcionário nos métodos Geter e Setters, eu tentei da seguinte forma  ***** function setData_adm($data_adm) {
        $this->data_adm = new DateTime($data_adm);        
    } **** Mas a data aparece como ano/mes/dia.

Comment: Seu get vai retornar um objeto DateTime, essa outra variável (que recebe o retorno do get) é quem vai formatar a data.

Comment: **Dá erro não esta retornando um objeto DateTime.

$funcionario->getData_adm()->format('d/m/Y'); 

Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\CasaDasMarmitas\index.php on line 20

Comment: Coloca o código do get e set da data na pergunta. Use o link [edit].

Comment: Já Editei a Pergunta coloquei todos os Get e set